# ffmpeg - SIGSTOP generate moov atom

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg in a script that does "motion detection".

The principle is as follows:

- ffmpeg is launched then immediately stopped with a "killall -s STOP ffmpeg";
- at each motion detection, a "killall -s CONT ffmpeg" is sent to the program in order to record the sequence;
- after X seconds, a "killall -s STOP ffmpeg" is sent pending a new motion detection.

When ffmpeg records following a SIGCONT, it is possible to properly stop ffmpeg with a "killall -s QUIT ffmpeg" and thus generate the atom moov.
However, I can't find a way to properly stop ffmpeg and generate the atom moov afterwards at a SIGSTOP. "killall -s QUIT ffmpeg" has no effect on a SIGSTOP ...

In summary, how can we generate the moov atom when ffmpeg is on SIGSTOP?

EDIT: resolved. Need to play with another signals. Ref: http://www.linux-france.org/article/man-fr/man7/signal-7.html

Comment: It is best to add the solution as an answer instead of an edit to your question.

Comment: What signals worked?